# Rails TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

if parsed_body.instance_of? Array
translated_response = translate_response(parsed_body)
translated_response[:dependency] = false if !(translated_response[:dependency].present?)
return translated_response
end
[]
end

Comment: Rosa, we need more context to address this question. Could you please paste in all of the code, with a short explanation of what is going on?

Comment: The error is most likely due to the fact that translated_response is of type Array, but you call [:dependency] on it. I would make sure #translate_response is returning what you expect.